# How to call a custom template phtml file on home page magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, phtml

[image: custom phtml call]

How to call `blog_slide.phtml` on home page or in static block.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="magentothem_blog/blog_slide.phtml"}}
```

i tried this but nothing happens.

```
<?php
$enabled_slide = Mage::getStoreConfig('blog/slide/enabled');
if($enabled_slide):
    $itemsTablet = $this->getConfig('itemsTablet');
    $itemsMobile = $this->getConfig('itemsMobile');
    $show_image = $this->getConfig('showimage');
    $show_title = $this->getConfig('showtitle');
    $show_author = $this->getConfig('showauthor');
    $show_time = $this->getConfig('showtime');
    $show_shortcontent = $this->getConfig('showshortcontent');
    $showcomment = $this->getConfig('showcomment');
    $show_readmore = $this->getConfig('showreadmore');

    echo "item".$itemsTablet;
?>
    <?php $post = $this->getRecent()->getFirstItem(); ?>
    <?php if($post): ?>
        <div class="menu-recent">
        <!--<div class="container">-->
            <div class="blog-titles ma-title"><h2>FROM THE BLOG</h2></div>
            <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="blog-image">
                        <?php if($show_image): ?>
                            <?php if($post->getAddress()): ?><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo '<img alt="" src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA). $post->getThumbnailimage().'"/>'; ?>
                            <?php if($post->getAddress()): ?></a><?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="time-conment">
                            <?php if($show_author) echo '<span class="author">By '.$post->getUser().'</span>'; 
                                if($show_author && $show_time) echo ''; 
                                if($show_time) echo '<span class="date-time"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>' .date("d M Y", $date).'</span>'; ?>
                            <?php if($showcomment) echo '<span class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>'.$this->getcountcomment($post->getPostId()) .' comments </span>' ?>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="blog-content">
                        <?php if($show_title): ?> <h3 class="blog-title"><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle() ?></a></h3> <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php $s = $post->getCreatedTime(); $date = strtotime($s); ?>
                        <?php if($show_shortcontent) echo '<p>' .strip_tags($this->getContentBlogSidebar($post->getShortContent(),120)) .'</p>';?>

                        <?php if($show_readmore): ?> <a class="readmore" href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>">Read more <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a> <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <!--</div>-->
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no blog matching the selection.') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: share `blog_slide.phtml` code

Comment: Did you check homepage by enabling template path hint from admin if your phtml file is being rendered?

Comment: Yes i did but no phtml file related to this shown. is there any thing wrong in  type="...."

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `local.xml`:

```
<cms_index_index>
   <reference name="content">
      <block type="core/template" name="my.new.custom.block" after="-" template="path_to_your_template.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: Where is the local.xml  file located? @PRINCE

Comment: app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourthemename/layout/local.xml @Rathinam

Comment: someone post most related for my point, could you help that : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/244255/57334

Comment: Answered, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245298/48355 @Rathinam